# SOAP client.php

Tags: php, soap

Bom dia. Estou tentando mexer com SOAP Web Service mas estou tendo problemas. Quando executo o arquivo client.php no navegador não funciona. Alguém sabe resolver?

server.php

```
<?php

$options = array('uri' => 'http://alairrepresentacoes-com-br.umbler.net/');
$server = new SoapServer(null, $options);

$server->setClass('MeuSoapServer');

$server->handle();

class MeuSoapServer {

    public function mensagem($nome)
    {
        return "Boas Vindas $nome !";
    }

    public function soma($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
?>
```

client.php

```
<?php

$options = array(
    'location' => 'http://alairrepresentacoes-com-br.umbler.net/servidor.php',
    'uri' => 'http://alairrepresentacoes-com-br.umbler.net/'
);

$client = new SoapClient(null, $options);


echo $client->mensagem('Douglas') . "<br />";
echo $client->soma(3, 5) . "<br />"

?>
```

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta um `;` no final de:

```
echo $client->soma(3, 5) . "<br />"
```

Deveria ser:

```
echo $client->soma(3, 5) . "<br />";
```

Logo pode estar ocorrendo este erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ';' in client.php on line 12
```

No entanto a exposição de erros ***deve estar desligada*** no seu site, logo você só receberá a mensagem `500 Internal Error Server`.

Note também que o seu servidor ***"talvez"*** não esteja com a extensão `Soap` para PHP ativada no `php.ini` e porque possivelmente os erros estão desligados no seu servidor você não pode notar as mensagens de erro, como por exemplo:

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in client.php on line 8

E esta

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapServer' not found in servidor.php on line 17

Note que no `servidor.php` você pode omitir o `?>` do final, pois ele é opcional e ajudará a evitar espaço em branco no XML do SOAP, que podem causar problemas.

### Ativar a extensão SOAP no PHP

Para fazer isto é necessário ter acesso ao `php.ini` do seu servidor, geralmente via CPanel ou SSH, se não tiver acesso é porque a sua hospedagem (se for uma hospedagem) não permite, então você terá que falar com o seu **suporte técnico**, no entanto se você tem acesso basta procurar dentro do `php.ini` a seguinte linha:

- Se for um servidor **Unix-like** (linux por exemplo)

  ```
  ;extension=soap.so
  ```
- Se for um servidor **Windows Server**

  ```
  ;extension=php_soap.dll
  ```

Então remova o `;` da frente deixando assim:

```
extension=soap.so
```

Ou se for WindowsServer, assim:

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

E então reinicie o servidor, no entanto se tiver controle sobre o servidor reinicie apenas o Apache ou o Ngnix ou o IIS (depende do tipo de servidor que usa), após isto deve funcionar.

Note que testei o seu código, e tive que ativar no meu servidor local o soap pelo php.ini, depois de ativar tive este resultado:

> Boas Vindas Douglas !
> 8

Ou seja `8` é a soma do `soma(3, 5)`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não sei como esqueci o ponto e vírgula kkkkk

Comment: Ficou muito completa sua resposta, ajudou demais. Gostaria só de perguntar sobre o uri e o location? Estão certos assim?

Comment: @ViníciusAssisNeves conforme o exemplo da documentação http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#example-6247 está correto sim.

Answer (score 0):

Se alguém está com um problema parecido, tente a resposta do Guilherme acima, se não der mexendo no php.ini igual ele falou (como no meu caso já estava certo no php.ini), remova todas as linhas do server.php após o *?>*. Digo, todas as linhas em branco, por algum motivo isso influencia.

Comment: Você pode omitir o `?>` se não houver mais conteudo abaixo, no php ele é opicional e ajuda a evitar espaço extras.

Comment: Aproveitei e adicionei a explicação na resposta: `Note que no servidor.php você pode omitir o ?> do final, pois ele é opcional e ajudará a evitar espaço em branco no XML do SOAP, que podem causar problemas.`.

Comment: Eu não sabia que era opcional, mas bom saber. Mas sua resposta foi muito útil, obrigado. Assim que eu tiver mais reputação aqui eu volto pra avaliar, precisa de pelo menos 15 pra avaliar kkk